# Twitter authorization using Hello.js libraries but unable to receive email

Tags: javascript, hello.js

I'm using Hello.js to make twitter login. I'm doing like this: http://adodson.com/hello.js/demos/twitter.html but i am unable to receive email. I have tried to set scope email but it doesn't working either.

This is my code:

```
var twitter = hello('twitter');

            twitter.login({ scope: 'email' }).then(function(auth){
                    return twitter.api('me');
                })
                .then( function(profile){
                    console.log(profile); // here I received full user data without email
                });
            };
```

Comment: I had enabled email feature in apps.twitter.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to enforce the email scope from a client to OAuth1 providers like the Twitter API. The notion of programmable scopes came in OAuth2.

HelloJS documents which programmable scopes are known to be supported per service. See the table at https://adodson.com/hello.js/#scope . This is not a comprehensive list so it can be fruitful to consult the providers documentation too.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the hello.all.js file. Add **include_email=true** expression to **verify_credentials.json**

```
---

get: {      me: 'account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true',

---
```

So I can get email

```
  function login(){
        // Twitter instance
        var twitter = hello('twitter');
        // Login
        twitter.login({ scope: 'email' }).then(function(r){
            // Get Profile
            return twitter.api('me');
        }, function(e) {
             alert('Signin error: ' + e.error.message);
         } )
        .then( function(p){
            // Get email
            alert('email: ' + p.email)
        }, log );       
   }       

   function log(){
       console.log(arguments);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get user email from twitter API. It is not available.

Edit: Sorry, it seems is possible now. Check here - https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials - but you need to email twitter.

> Requesting a user’s email address requires your application to be
>   whitelisted by Twitter. To request access, please use this form.
>
> Once whitelisted, the “Request email addresses from users” checkbox
>   will be available under your app permissions on apps.twitter.com.
>   Privacy Policy URL and Terms of Service URL fields will also be
>   available under settings which are required for email access. If
>   enabled, users will be informed via the oauth/authorize dialog that
>   your app can access their email address.

Comment: I already to this and I have access. but in my opinion hello.js doesn't have email scope support :/

Comment: There is no need to email Twitter any longer as of September 2017. You just tick the appropriate checkbox in the app's settings (on the permissions tab).